# Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/xx/xx/includes/src/__default.php on line 29313

Tags: php, magento-1.9

i just did all these solution but failed to get solution

1. 777 permission to your magento folder.
2. chmod 775 lib/Magento/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Comment: View this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/62201

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Moving+Magento+to+Another+Server) and also [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62196/magento-upgrade-fatal-error-class-magento-db-adapter-pdo-mysql-not-found-in/62201#62201)

Also **enable pdo extension** on your server

You need to enable the PDO and PDO_MYSQL extensions in your php.ini file.
go to your  php.ini file Which is located inside the directory where PHP was installed and remove the comments (;) in the lines bellow so

```
;extension=php_pdo.dll to  extension=php_pdo.dll
```

**On a windows server you can add the following lines in your php.ini**

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

**On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines**

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

some webhosts don't allow to edit the php ini directly so you need to talk to them to give you this permission, or them uncomment these lines I posted in php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

I think it's compilation issue.

Disable Magento compiler via SSH

```
php -f shell/compiler.php clear
php -f shell/compiler.php disable
```

Then clear cache, if works then compile again